# When is complete-class scope really useful in default arguments, default member initializers and exception specification?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-design

The standard says that default arguments, class member default initializers and method exception specifications should be parsed in a complete-class context; that is, the class should be regarded as complete within those expressions or specifiers. Naturally, it follows that *all* the names defined in the scope of the class should be visible to those expressions, even the names declared/defined after the expression:

```
struct Test
{
    // Well-formed, `bar` is looked up in complete-class context:
    static void foo() noexcept(noexcept(bar()));

    static void bar() noexcept;
};
```

I imagine, this requirement puts a lot of burden on the compilers: they have little choice but to postpone the parsing of those expressions to until the class definition is complete (or even further, in case of nested classes), which leads to other problems and pitfalls.

Which is why I can't help wondering: **Why? What good does it do?**
Isn't it always possible to reorder the member declarations in such a way that a name is always declared before it is used (by *before* I mean up the source text flow).

**Could you come up with an example which cannot be reordered, so that a default argument, a default initializer and an exception specification clearly *must* be parsed in the complete-class context?**

Comment: I guess it's because you are putting more burden on the compiler otherwise - default arguments and default initializers can't be simply plugged in at the caller site.

Comment: Compilers actually do parse such things eagerly, resulting in issues like [CWG325](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#325).

Answer (score 1):

Counter example:

```
struct Test
{
    // Well-formed, `bar` is looked up in complete-class context:
    static void foo() noexcept(noexcept(bar()));

    static decltype(foo()) bar() noexcept;
};
```

It maybe not a realistic example (I could explicity write `void` instead), but disallowing such mutual dependency would be a major restriction that would be unnecessary, because compilers can handle code like the above.

Different example that is maybe more addressing your question:

```
struct Test
{
    // Well-formed, `bar` is looked up in complete-class context:
    static void foo() noexcept(noexcept(bar()));

    static void bar(decltype(foo) f = foo) noexcept;
};
```

Comment: not sure if I understood the question correctly. I'll just leave the answer...

Comment: I think you understood the question correctly: I was indeed asking for a counter example. However, I was hoping to see the ultimate counter example, the one that _can't be written without this complete-class context_...

Comment: @IgorG I think that is difficult because with lots of effort almost any restriction can be bypassed. Though, i'd be happy to be proven wrong by a different answer

Comment: May I ask if that second example is purely synthetic? Or have you really seen code like this in a real project, where it serves a good purpose?

Comment: @IgorG i think a class with only static methods is already purely synthetic ;). I dont remember to come across this, but If I would write a member function that takes a member function as parameter, this is what I would write.

Comment: @IgorG only the noexcept specification would probably be swapped (ie bar is noexcept if foo is), but then it wouldn't be a counter example anymore